# nmcli with groovy in soapui

Tags: command-line, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to change wifi signal using groovy script in soapui. I'm using the following sentence:

```
"nmcli con uo id 'SSDI'".execute()
```

Executing this command in console is working perfectly, but executing in soapui does nothing. I have been testing with others commands and work correctly.

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: how do you know it gets executed at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
def command = ['nmcli', 'con', 'uo', 'id', 'SSDI']
def proc = command.execute()                 
proc.waitFor()                               

println "return code: ${proc.exitValue()}"
println "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}"
```